# is cp-kafka-connect open source or proprietary components?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

On the [docker configuration website of confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/docs/configuration.html), regarding the open-source/enterprise identity, the naming convention and the table notes seems to be contradictory.

cp-kafka-connect does not have the cp-enterprise prefix, and according to the text description they are presumably open source.

However, in the table, it is marked as Enterprise.

[image: screenshot]

I wonder if are they open-source at all? and what is the right procedure to use the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find [Dockerfile here](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images)

> cp-kafka-connect does not have the cp-enterprise prefix

`cp-enterprise-replicator` **is** the enterprise Kafka Connect image. You can add any other Kafka Connect plugin to it just as you can add them to the other one

The other one contains all the open source Connects on Confluent Github (HDFS, S3, JDBC, and Elasticsearch), but it's marked as Enterprise in that column because apparently Control Center package is included

> what is the right procedure to use the image?

The enterprise images can be configured with a Confluent License key. The open source images you're welcome to pull and extend for your own purposes

Also, read the note

> Note: The Kafka Connect and KSQL Server images are labeled as "Enterprise" simply because they contain Confluent monitoring interceptors. The monitoring interceptors enable connectors and KSQL queries to collect the metrics which can be visualized in Confluent Control Center. The Kafka Connect image includes Confluent Control Center in its entirety, while the KSQL Server image just includes the monitoring interceptors. No explicit license is required when using the Kafka Connect or the KSQL Server image on their own.